# 'OR' is not working in SQL statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql

I am trying to come up with a SQL statement that will select the data based on multiple criteria and using multiple fields, but it is not returning the correct results back.

Example: `Depth < 1 OR Depth > 7 OR Offset < 9 OR HSDV > 4 OR VSDV > 12`

I want all points that meet just one of these criteria to be selected.

Comment: Are you getting no results at all or incorrect results?

Comment: usually just the first part of the statement is retuned 'Depth < 1'

Comment: It would help if you included all of the relevant SQL statement in the question.

Comment: How are you executing the query? Using Select by Attributes?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table_name]
WHERE (Depth < 1 OR Depth > 7) OR Offset < 9 OR (HSDV > 4 OR VSDV > 12)
```

Moreover, I am thinking that this part `HSDV > 4 OR VSDV > 12` of your query does not make much sense (as well as `HSDV < 4 OR VSDV < 12`) because `HSDV > 4` already includes `VSDV > 12` (alternatively `VSDV < 12` already includes `HSDV < 4`). You may rather use `HSDV < 4 OR VSDV > 12` if you want values less then 4 and more then 12, otherwise you can use `HSDV > 4 OR VSDV < 12` to get values in the range between 4 and 12.

Tutorials on a topic SQL Operators (AND and OR) and their combination could be found here:

- [SQL: Combining the AND and OR Conditions](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php)
- [SQL AND, OR and NOT Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Comment: I will give this a try